# Is a "heist" somehow more remarkable, or different in nature, from a robbery?

Tags: meaning

Am I wrong to assume a heist in someway implies the existence of a particular plan?

Is it more of an anglo or american term? Does it mean the same thing across the pond?

(Also: is it pronounced more like heest or hyst?)

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heist
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heist

Comment: http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=heist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pronounced like high-st.  Not sure which side of the pond is across the pond, but in America, it generally does bring up images of further planning or more complexity since it's normally a bigger job than a simple robbery.